# align hint text in EditText inputType=textPassword, for right-to-left (RTL) languages

Tags: android, android-edittext, right-to-left, hint

I have an EditText with `inputType` set to `textPassword`.
I want that the input will be numbers from left to right but I want to align the hint to the right of the EditText.
When I tried `gravity=right` it looked okay but when a user clicks on the EditText the cursor is at the most left location and he can't delete the text. If he wants to delete the text he needs to place the cursor at the most right location.

Any idea how I can enjoy both worlds?

Use EditText with `inputType=textPassword`, hint aligned to the right and insert numbers from left to right?

Note: It appears to be a bug in the Android framework, when using android:inputType="textPassword": https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201471

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txt_password"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="סיסמא"
        android:gravity="right" />
```

[image: clicking the edittext puts the cursor at the left position and I can't delete the text now]

[image: empty edittext]
Thanks

Comment: This answer might be useful (or possible duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403731/hint-alignment-to-the-right-of-password-edittext

Answer (score 0):

The EditText is built to align the hint text the same as the user-entered text. The way I have accomplished this, by placing both images and text to the right side of an EditText, is just to define another view that is aligned to the right of it.

You need to have the parent view be a RelativeLayout to do this, but it works well:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/test" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/hint"
   android:text="Something"
   android:layout_alignRight="@id/test"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@id/test"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand you solution. how another textview will help me in here?

Answer (score 0):

I want to complete @Greg Ennis
I hope this can help you
I use a EditText for password and a TextView for it's hint like below:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/input_login"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint"
        />
      <TextView android:id="@+id/hint"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/password"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/password"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/password"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and I write following code in onCreate method to hide hint TextView when enter password:

```
    EditText edtPassword;
    TextView txtHint;
    edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    txtHint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hint);

    edtPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String enterPass = edtPassword.getText().toString();

            if(start == 0){
                txtHint.setHint(R.string.hint_password);


            }else {
                txtHint.setHint("");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```